# XHR consulta a PHP y devuelve 0

Tags: javascript, php

Envío una petición fetch a php y retorna 0 o "esta solicitud no tiene disponibles datos de respuesta".

Son combos que en el evento clic están asociados, por ejemplo si selecciona un ingrediente, trae el precio y la unidad de medida.

Este es el código de JavaScript

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        const ingSelect = document.querySelectorAll('.ingSelect'); //ingSelect es el combo
        ingSelect.forEach(elem => (
            elem.addEventListener('change', function () {
            
                const id = this.dataset.id;
                
                const unidadInput = document.getElementById('unidad_id' + id);
                const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

                xhr.open('GET', '/app/generar_combo_unidades.php?i=' + this.value);
    
                xhr.withCredentials = true;
                xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
                 
                    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                        if (xhr.status === 200) {
                            unidadInput.value = xhr.responseText;
                        }
                    }
                });
                //hice un console log y la respuesta es vacia
                xhr.send(null);
            }))
        )
    })
</script>
```

Este es el php

```php
<?php

$db = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'user', '', 'db');
mysqli_set_charset($db, 'utf8mb4');

$id_ingrediente = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_GET['i']);

$query = "SELECT unidades.nombre, unidades.unidad_id
          FROM unidades INNER JOIN ingredientes WHERE ingredientes.ingrediente_id = $id_ingrediente
          AND ingredientes.unidad_id = unidades.unidad_id";

$res = mysqli_query($db, $query);

$fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
    echo $fila['nombre'] ;
```

Probé poniendo un `echo('hola')` en el php y sigue sin devolver nada.

Comment: En tu php trata de  devolver la respuesta en formato json ej. echo json_encode({"mensaje":"hola"}). Para tu codigo en vez de echo $fila['nombre']. prueba con echo json_encode($fila).

Comment: Es increíble no hace nada, sigue devolviendo 0, tengo la sensacion de que la peticion no llega al php, como que es bloqueada antes pero no encuentro como resolverlo.